# WP8.1 Calendar look-alike

Tags: calendar, windows-phone-8.1

I'm searching for a WindowsPhone 8.1 Calendar look-alike. I don't want to store any data/appointments in it, I just want the monthly view as a date-picker control, as I do not like the normal date-picker.

I came across `WinRTXamlToolkit` that does offer a calendar, but I don't like the style of it. It's too bulgy for me.

See attached an image of what I want (without the colored stripes)

[image]

Comment: Create your own control.  Search how to draw a rectangle.  Then multiple that by 35.  Then learn how to incorporate it such that there's a number on the bottom left in the `ItemDataTemplate` of a `WrapGrid` and you're done.  It's not that hard to break it down in to simple steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out Telerik or Syncfusion?  They both offer calendar controls that are customizable.

http://www.telerik.com/windows-universal-ui

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/calendar

Comment: are there any free solutions for that?

Comment: @user3079834 If you're an individual developer or using it for a small business you can get the syncfusion controls for free:
[http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense)